# Python: Check second variable if first variable is True?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I have a script that checks bools through if statements and then executes code. What I am trying to do is make it so that:

```
if variable a is True, check if b is True and execute code
if variable a is False, execute the same code mentioned before
```

A simplified version of what I currently have is this:

```
if a:
    if b:
        print('foo')
else:
    print('foo')
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't require me  to write `print('foo')` twice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
if not a or (a and b):
    print('foo')
```

Let's talk this step by step:
When is `print('foo')` executed?

1. When `a` and `b` are both `True`.
2. When `else` is executed, what is `else`? The opposite of the previous `if` so `not a`.

Finally you wish to display `'foo'` in one case or the other.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, by simplifying the logic equation:

**NOTE:** *You might want to avoid this unless you know what you are doing! Clarity is often way better than shortness. Trust my advice! I've been through there! ;)*

```
if not a or b: 
   print('foo')
```

Because if `not a` is not `True`, then `a` must be `True` (the second part of `or`), so the `a and b` can be simplified in just `b` (because we do know as a fact that `a` is `True` in this situation, so `a and b` is the same as `True and b` so we can drop the first part safely).

Comment: Also you can read more about why `¬a⋁(a⋀b)≣¬a⋀b`, by learning [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra), [propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) and [first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

Comment: Thanks! The logic is pretty simple so I probably wont have any problems, but I will be careful

Answer (score 0):

While JeromeJ's answer is correct, an alternative can be:

```
print("foo" if ((not a) or (a and b)) else '')
```

It will print a blank line if not printing "foo", though.

If you don't want that to happen, you could exploit it like this:

```
print("foo") if ((not a) or (a and b)) else ''
```

`''` or anything else could be used as it will be thrown away in the nature.

Comment: No, it won't. It won't do anything if the condition is not fulfilled. I would even say your way of doing it is abusing the `if...else` expression. ITYM `print("foo" if ((not a) or (a and b)) else '')` instead...